# How to sign message using Foundry?

Tags: foundry, forge

The current [documentation](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/sign) includes a way to sign messages; however, it returns `(v, r, s)` values. How to construct a signature from these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct signatures from `(v,r,s)`, you can use:

```
bytes memory test = abi.encodePacked(r, s, v);
console.logBytes(test);
```